# ESLint in Visual Studio - Web Analyzer - Custom .eslintrc location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, eslint

Trying to setup ESLinting in Visual Studio 2015. As far as I know the only way to enable it is to use [Web Analyzer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6edc26d4-47d8-4987-82ee-7c820d79be1d) for that.

My `.eslintrc.json` is in the project root folder `c:\code\myproject\` not in the user profile `c:\Users\RootNode\`.

The problem is that Web Analyzer does not let you change the location of the .eslintrc but reads it always from the user profile. How to get ESLinting working in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your .eslintrc has the json extension which is [not currently supported.](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebAnalyzer/issues/14) Try changing the filename to just `.eslintrc`.

Comment: Just renaming the file does not help. Still the core problem persists. Web analyzer reads the config always from %USERPROFILE%. In my case I want it to be read from the local root (project root). And there seems no way to configure where the .eslintrc is read. Many other editor's (emacs, sublime text, vs code) eslint plugins read the .eslintrc first from the local project root, and only if not found, then they try to read it from user profile.

Comment: Try uninstalling Web Analyzer and installing .Net Core from here https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798481 which includes the latest version of Web Analyzer. Also put your .eslintrc through a JSON validator or better yet try it with another eslint tool to make sure it is a valid eslintrc.

Answer (score 0):

There is new tooling for vs2015 which has ESLint built in like is vs2017. I couldn't get it to work without using a .eslintrc.js file, but you may have better luck with .json.

You should see the new Web tooling in "Tools" --> "Extensions and Updates"

After you download you can open the config by going to "Tools" --> "Web Code analysis" --> "Edit ESLint..."

Even if you don't use the new web tooling, to include a custom `.eslintrc.js` just point to it from the root config(`C:\Users\(username)`) by adding `"extends":"(path to the file in your project)"`. There is no work-around I know of to ignore the root config and use only the project config.

Sorry if that's not exactly what you're looking for, but it works on my vs2015 with windows 10.